# Include empty value fields in jQuery .serialize()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to submit a form via jQuery $.post and serialize the form data via

```
$('form').serialize();
```

Unfortunately fields with unchecked **radiobutton** or **checkboxes** are not being serialized, ergo submitted.

Is there a way to include ALL fields regardless of whether they contain a value or not?

I guess this only affects fields like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="some_name[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="some_name[]" value="2" />
```

Comment: they will only be submitting (and serialized) if they were checked, otherwise nothing is submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Make your own version of serialize :

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.mySerialize = function() {
    var returning = '';
    $('input, textarea',this).each(function(){
          var name = this.name;
          var value = this.value;
          returning += name + '=' + value + '&';
    })
    return returning;

  };
})( jQuery );


$('form').mySerialize();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/apGC3/

Answer (score -2):

You seem to be mistaken as shown in this [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ag5vq/2/). The `foo` field is included even if it doesn't contain any value:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="text" name="bar" value="baz" />
</form>
```

and then:

```
alert($('form').serialize());
```

prints (as expected):

```
foo=&bar=baz
```

Comment: but what about unchecked checkboxes? I think that is the issue.

Comment: @Neal, that's normal and not related to jQuery. Unchecked checkbox values are not sent to the server with normal form submissions and the jQuery.serialize method is coherent with this behavior. By the way that's the reason why ASP.NET MVC CheckBoxFor helper generates a hidden input value with the same name as the checkbox.

Comment: I realize that. I know that but i think that is what the OP is complaining abt (it makes no sense, i agree)

Comment: @neal: that's exactly my problem. so what if multiple checkboxes were checked? i guess i need to use a jquery form plugin, then?

Answer (score -2):

DEMO: http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/bbfdd/2

result: `bar=`

```
<form> 
<input name="bar" /> 
</form> 
<script> 
$(function(){ 
   $("input").click(function(){ 
       alert($("form").serialize()); 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```