# How to get all form elements pushed in an array including the radio elements using each loop in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

This is the jQuery Code I am executing:

```
var fieldCheck = [], proceedNext = true;
$("form#form1 [id^=patient_]").each(function() {
  if(!$.trim($(this).val())) {
    proceedNext = false;
    fieldCheck.push(" "+$('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').html());
  }
});

if(!$("form#form1 input[name='patient_gender']:checked").val()) {
  proceedNext = false;
  fieldCheck.push(" "+"Gender");
}

if(!$("form#form1 input[name='patient_alcoholic']:checked").val()) {
  proceedNext = false;
  fieldCheck.push(" "+"Alcoholic Status");
}

if(!$("form#form1 input[name='patient_tobacco']:checked").val()) {
  proceedNext = false;
  fieldCheck.push(" "+"Tobacco Status");
}

if(proceedNext) {
  var inpDataArray = [];
  $("form#form1").each(function() {
    var _inputDataArray = [];
    $(this).find("input[type='text'], textarea, select").each(function(index, value) {
      _inputDataArray.push($(this).val());
    }); 
    inpDataArray.push(_inputDataArray);
  }); 

  inpDataArray.push($('input[name=patient_gender]:checked').val());            
  inpDataArray.push($('input[name=patient_alcoholic]:checked').val());           
  inpDataArray.push($('input[name=patient_tobacco]:checked').val());
  console.log(inpDataArray);
  return false;
}
```

This is my HTML Code:

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-body">
              <div class="row"> 
                    {{-- Reg id --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patient_HospitalUid" name="patient_HospitalUid">
                                <label for="patient_HospitalUid">Hospital UID / MRD Number</label> <span class="help-block">Hospital UID / MRD Number</span>
                          </div>
                    </div> 
                    {{-- First Name --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patient_firstname" name="patient_patient_firstname">
                                <label for="patient_firstname">First Name</label> <span class="help-block">Patient's First Name</span>
                          </div>
                    </div> 
                    {{-- Last Name --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patient_lastname" name="patient_patient_lastname">
                                <label for="patient_lastname">Last Name</label> <span class="help-block">Patient's Last Name</span>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- Date of Birth --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <input class="form-control date-picker" size="16" type="text" value="" id="patient_dob" name="patient_patient_dob" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" onblur="this.className += ' edited'" />
                                <label for="patient_dob">Date of Birth</label> <span class="help-block"> Select Date of Birth </span>
                          </div>
                    </div> 
                    {{-- Age --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patient_age" name="patient_age">
                                <label for="patient_age">Age</label> <span class="help-block">Patient's Age</span>
                          </div>
                    </div> 
                    {{-- Gender --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-radios">
                                <label>Gender</label>
                                <div class="md-radio-inline">
                                      <div class="md-radio">
                                            <input type="radio" id="patient_genderMale" name="patient_gender" data-value="Gender" value="male" class="md-radiobtn">
                                            <label for="patient_genderMale"> <span></span> <span class="check"></span> <span class="box"></span> Male </label>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="md-radio">
                                            <input type="radio" id="patient_genderFemale" name="patient_gender" value="female" class="md-radiobtn">
                                            <label for="patient_genderFemale"> <span></span> <span class="check"></span> <span class="box"></span> Female </label>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="md-radio">
                                            <input type="radio" id="patient_genderSkip" name="patient_gender" value="other" class="md-radiobtn">
                                            <label for="patient_genderSkip"> <span></span> <span class="check"></span> <span class="box"></span> Other </label>
                                      </div>
                                </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- Mobile No --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patient_mobile" name="patient_mobile">
                                <label for="patient_mobile">Mobile No</label> <span class="help-block">Patient's Mobile No</span>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- Landline No --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patientopt_landline" name="patientopt_landline">
                                <label for="patientopt_landline">Landline No.</label> <span class="help-block">Patient's Landline No.</span>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- Email-ID --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patientopt_email" name="patientopt_email">
                                <label for="patientopt_email">E-mail address</label> <span class="help-block">Patient's E-mail address</span>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- Reffered By --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patient_ReferredBy" name="patient_ReferredBy">
                                <label for="patient_ReferredBy">Referred By</label> <span class="help-block">Patient's Referred By</span>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- Address --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="patient_address" rows="2" cols="2" name="patient_address"></textarea>
                                <label for="patient_address">Address</label> <span class="help-block">Patient's Address</span>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- State --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
                                <select class="form-control" id="patient_state" name="patient_state">
                                      <option selected disabled value="">Select State</option> @if(!empty($states)) @foreach($states as $state)
                                      <option value="{{ $state['name'] }}"> {{ $state['name'] }}</option> @endforeach @else
                                      <option value="">No data found</option>
                                      <option value="maharashtra">Maharashtra</option> @endif </select>
                                <label for="patient_state">State</label>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- City --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
                                <select class="form-control" id="patient_city" name="patient_city">
                                      <option selected disabled value="">Select City</option>
                                      <option value="amravati">Amravati</option>
                                </select>
                                <label for="patient_city">City</label>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- Pincode --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patient_pincode" name="patient_pincode">
                                <label for="patient_pincode">Pincode</label> <span class="help-block">Patient's Pincode</span>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- BloodGroup --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input has-success">
                                <select class="form-control" id="patient_bloodgroup" name="patient_bloodgroup">
                                      <option selected disabled value=""> Select Bloodgroup</option>
                                      <option value="bloodGrpId_1">AB+ve</option>
                                </select>
                                <label for="patient_bloodgroup">Bloodgroup</label>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- Weight --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patient_weight" name="patient_weight">
                                <label for="patient_weight">Weight (In Kgs)</label> <span class="help-block">Patient's Weight (In Kgs)</span>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- Height --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patient_height" name="patient_height">
                                <label for="patient_height">Height</label> <span class="help-block">Patient's Height</span>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- BMI --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patient_bmi" name="patient_bmi">
                                <label for="patient_bmi">BMI</label> <span class="help-block">Patient's BMI</span>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- Alcoholic --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-radios">
                                <label>Alcoholic?</label>
                                <div class="md-radio-inline">
                                      <div class="md-radio">
                                            <input type="radio" id="patient_alcoholicYes" data-value="Alcoholic Staus" name="patient_alcoholic" value="yes" class="md-radiobtn">
                                            <label for="patient_alcoholicYes"> <span></span> <span class="check"></span> <span class="box"></span> Yes </label>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="md-radio">
                                            <input type="radio" id="patient_alcoholicNo" name="patient_alcoholic" class="md-radiobtn" value="no">
                                            <label for="patient_alcoholicNo"> <span></span> <span class="check"></span> <span class="box"></span> No </label>
                                      </div>
                                </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- Tobacco --}}
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                          <div class="form-group form-md-radios">
                                <label>Tobacco?</label>
                                <div class="md-radio-inline">
                                      <div class="md-radio">
                                            <input type="radio" id="patient_tobaccoYes" data-value="Tobacco Status" name="patient_tobacco" value="yes" class="md-radiobtn">
                                            <label for="patient_tobaccoYes"> <span></span> <span class="check"></span> <span class="box"></span> Yes </label>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="md-radio">
                                            <input type="radio" id="tobacco_no" name="patient_tobacco" class="md-radiobtn" value="no">
                                            <label for="tobacco_no"> <span></span> <span class="check"></span> <span class="box"></span> No </label>
                                      </div>
                                </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>
  </form>
```

What I am trying to achieve is I have a form and it has `text-area, text, radio, select` what I am trying to achieve I that when I am iterating the loop in JQuery I want everything stored in an array currently I am not able to interate the radio button in the same loop so I am using method outside to achieve it but it is creating is another array. Also what I am trying to achieve is that when the value is being pushed also I want to get the value of the label like for example if `gender is clicked on female` then I want to achieve something like `gender: male`, `address: address entered` and so on. How to achieve it? I am not able to achieve is.

Comment: How about $(“form1”).serialize() ?

Comment: I tried that but couldn't achieve the desired result :(

Comment: if I keep a field blank then the serialize function doesn't display that field what I want is whether the field is inputted or left empty I will push it I array like if some field is inputted then O/p: `address: some value` if not inputted then O/p: 'address: ""'

Comment: Serialize works like the form submit. Why not handle missing fields as empty on the server? If you must, then this is likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179695/include-empty-value-fields-in-jquery-serialize

Comment: I have 17 forms on that page and I am trying to make very less use of server processing. So mainly I have 10 bootstrap wizard pages, 6 modals, and 1 additional form and before proceeding to each form I need to have some validations. That's why I am trying to do it on JS Side.